# Java: "Anonymous" array in for-each-loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

While I was trying something special in for loop I recognized that Java doesn't seem to like putting an anonymous array right as the source for a for-each-loop:

```
for (String crt : {"a","b","c"} ) {
    doSomething();
}
```

actually doesn't work while

```
String[] arr = {"a","b","c"};
for (String crt : arr ) {
    doSomething();
}
```

does.

Even casting the array to String[] doesn't help. When moving the cursor over the first version, eclipse tells me:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String` while meaning "crt".

Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't actually **claim** to have **found** a bug. I just **ask** whether it **could be** a bug. And it's strange that in one part this type of expression works and in another it doesn't. Not very consistent in my eyes.

Comment: for the record, @JoachimSauer was referring to the section _Don't rush to claim that you have found a bug._ the up-to-date URL is http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idp5122192

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This will work:

```
for (String crt : new String[]{"a","b","c"} ) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The Java language provides the `{"a","b","c"}` form as a shortcut, but it is only possible during assignment. It's possible this is to avoid possible ambiguities during parsing, in some positions `{}` could be interpreted as a code block.

The right way to do it would be how noah suggests, with `new String[]{"a","b","c"}`.

Comment: Please note that that short form isn't allowed in all assignments. It is allowed only in initializations.

Comment: @Joachim: interesting fact. This pretty much solves my question, thanks for pointing it out.
@Tom Castle: +1 Good answer

Answer (score 4):

Dunno, what about this? :) Pity there's no succinct version. Suppose you could use Groovy or Scala if you wanted anything like that :)

```
for (String s : Arrays.asList("a","b","c")) {
    hmm(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want

```
for (String crt : new String [] {"a","b","c"} ) {
    doSomething();
}
```

I use IntelliJ and it says put the message "expression expected" on the right-hand side of the colon in the for-loop, which seems more accurate.

I should add that IntelliJ also offers to add the "new String []" automagically for me.