# Initializing Java object instances containing an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, initialization

The following code is correct:

```
public Sample mOboeSamples[] = { new Sample(1,1), new Sample(1,2) };
public Sample mGuitarSamples[] = { new Sample(1,1), new Sample(1,2) };
public SampleSet mSampleSet[] = { 
        new SampleSet( "oboe",  mOboeSamples ),
        new SampleSet( "guitar", mGuitarSamples)
        };
```

but I'd like to write something like:

```
public SampleSet mSampleSet[] = { 
        new SampleSet( "oboe",  { new Sample(1,1), new Sample(1,2) } ),
        new SampleSet( "guitar", { new Sample(1,1), new Sample(1,2) } )
        };
```

This does not compile.

Is there some bit of syntax I'm missing, or is this a language 'feature'?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358866/java-anonymous-array-in-for-each-loop/2358904#2358904 :)

Comment: Did any of the answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 11):

You need to tell it the type of the arrays you're passing as parameters:

```
public SampleSet mSampleSet[] = { 
    new SampleSet( "oboe",   new Sample[] { new Sample(1,1), new Sample(1,2) } ),
    new SampleSet( "guitar", new Sample[] { new Sample(1,1), new Sample(1,2) } )
};
```

Without the `new` expression, the braces aren't valid syntactically (because they're initializers -- in this case -- but you haven't said there's anything there to initialize).

Answer (score 2):

Use [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
 SampleSet(String name, Sample... samples) {
    // exactly the same code as before should work
 }
```

Then you can do

```
 new SampleSet("oboe", new Sample(1, 1), new Sample(1, 2));
```