# Iterate over static array in java without array variable

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, iteration, array-initialization

In Ruby, I can do something like:

```
["FOO", "BAR"].each do { |str| puts str }
```

Iterating over an array defined in the statement in which I'm using it.  Since I can define an array in Java like:

```
String[] array = { "FOO", "BAR" };
```

I know I can avoid defining the variable by setting up a loop like:

```
for (String str : new String[] { "FOO", "BAR" }) { ... }
```

But, I was hoping java might have something more terse, **WITHOUT defining a variable containing the array first**, and also allow me to avoid the dynamic allocation, is there a syntax like:

```
for (String str : { "FOO", "BAR" }) { ... }
```

That is more terse that will work with Java that I'm missing, or is the solution I've got above my only option?

Comment: Good question. It would be interesting to see if there's any easier way to define literal data structures.

Comment: Just found this (nearly identical) question while surfing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358866/java-anonymous-array-in-for-each-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

The best you can do is

```
    for(String s : Arrays.asList("a", "b")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

`java.util.Arrays` gives a method `asList(...)` which is a var-arg method, and it can be used to create `List` (which is dynamic array) on fly.

In this way you can **declare** and **iterate** over an array in same statement

Comment: Since Java 11, you can replace `Arrays.asList` with `List.of`. And also `String` with `var`, because the type can be inferred from the types in the list.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8, you will be able to do the following:

```
Stream.of("FOO", "BAR").forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

This uses the new [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) package and [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: Thanks -- I thought Java8 might add something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Languages like Java are incredibly verbose compared to terse languages like Ruby. It looks to me like what you already have is your best bet:

```
for (String str : new String[] { "FOO", "BAR" }) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about syntactic sugar for collections as much as anything. However, in Java 8 you can say

`Arrays.asList("a", "b").forEach(System.out::println);`

where you can of course substitute your own method literal that's compatible with `Consumer<T>`.